# python string replace digits

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace certain parts of the string below.

```
'''<td align="center"> 5 </td> <td> align="center"> 0.0001 </td>'''
```

I need to remove the `<td>` tag if there is a '0.'(decmial occurrence). i.e. the output should be

```
'''<td align="center"> 5 </td>'''
```

I have tried this

```
data = ' '.join(data.split())<br>
l = data.replace('<td align="center"> 0.r"\d" </td>', "")
```

but didn't succeed. Could anyone please help me with doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do some users not accept answers ? Actually, why are there *ever* questions asked which are then not accepted? Surely there can't be tht many people who, after asking a question, completely lost access to the Internet forever?

Comment: [Obligatory reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566644)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While both of the regular expression examples work, I would advice **against** using regexp.

*Especially if the data is a full html document*, you should go for html-aware parser, such as `lxml.html` e.g.:

```
from lxml import html
t = html.fromstring(text)
tds = t.xpath("table/tbody/tr[2]/td")
for td in tds:
    if tds.text.startswith("0."):
        td.getparent().remove(td)
text = html.tostring(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with regular expression:

```
import re
s = "<td align='center'> 5 </td><td align='center'>0.00001</td>"
re.sub("<td align='center'>0.\d+</td>", "", s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to check for the `<td>` and if it matches, you can use `re.sub()` to replace it with what ever you want.

```
pattern = '\"<td align=\"center\"> 0.[0-9]+ </td>\"'
p = re.compile(pattern)
p.sub('', my_string)
```

where `my_string` contains the string you want to operate on, hope this helps